# Is it possible to increment variable names in python?

Tags: python, variables, python-imaging-library, variable-assignment, python-3.5

I am trying to achieve a program that breaks down every line of an image into its RGB Figure (this bit i have done) then assign this to a increasing variable that corresponds to its row number. I want to achieve the following result:

```
(input) line1
(output) (whatever the value is, in this form ([(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)]) e.g.
```

so far i have done this:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\CWD")
im = Image.open("bw.jpg")
data_RGB = im.convert("RGB")
actual = list(data_RGB.getdata())
size = im.size[0]
counter = 0

while counter != size:
    lowerbound = 0
    upperbound = size
    print (actual[(0+lowerbound):(0+upperbound)])
    print("")
    #current_line = (actual[(0+lowerbound):(0+upperbound)])
    print("")
    counter = counter + 1
    (lowerbound) = int(lowerbound) + size
    (upperbound) = int(upperbound) + size
```

I have tried to solve the problem down this route:

```
for x in list(range(size+1)):
print("line", x, "is", current_line)
```

but ofcource this prints what current_line is at a static point, the first point that it is.

So my question is, is there a way in which i can increase my variable name by +1 for the corresponding row.

Can anyone give me a start for a solution?

Comment: Just use a dictionary.

Comment: Why not use a list, with the line number as the index?

Comment: (By the way, the answer to any "is it possible" question in python is almost always "yes" - but in many cases it's a very bad idea).

Comment: Can you explain how I would use line numbers as my index?

Comment: Although now marked ' duplicate ' the other page does not answer my question?

Comment: @JordanMazefield actually - it does. Have a look at pythons [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) or [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Please, do explain how I would do this using my situation i cannot see how the pages help.